# Generate Parse Crash Report from Caught Exceptions on Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to get an Exception into the Parse crash reporting pipeline without letting the app crash.

Using Parse 1.9.1, I don't see any API calls that allow user-generated exceptions to be sent off to the crash reports without letting the exception crash the app.  Parse already has a good UI for showing the exceptions, so why would I home-roll a solution to get stack traces out from caught exceptions?

I tried instantiating a ParseException from a throwable, but this does not implicitly result in a crash report being sent.  I also tried throwing an Exception in an anonymous Runnable, but run() can't throw an Exception due to parent class.

There has to be another API within the Parse libraries to send the reports.  I searched the API for signatures accepting Throwable, but only found the constructors for ParseException in the API docs.  Is there a way to analyze the jar and find private methods used to send Throwables to the Parse cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible as there is no open API to send exceptions to Parse.

However, if you feel this will be useful (which I personally do), you can go to their [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers) and submit it as a feature request.